# How can I pass a dependancy to a URLProtocol subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, urlsession, nsurlprotocol

I have been working on an interceptor for adding auth headers to network requests in my app.

```swift
final class AuthInterceptor: URLProtocol {


    private var token: String = "my.access.token"   
    private var dataTask: URLSessionTask?
    private struct UnexpectedValuesRepresentationError: Error { }
    
    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        guard URLProtocol.property(forKey: "is_handled", in: request) as? Bool == nil else { return false }

        return true
        
        //return false // URL Loading System will handle the request using the system’s default behavior
    }
    
    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        return request
    }
    
    override func startLoading() {
        guard let mutableRequest = (request as NSURLRequest).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableURLRequest else { return }
        URLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "is_handled", in: mutableRequest)
        mutableRequest.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: mutableRequest as URLRequest) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if let error = error {
                self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
            } else if let data = data, let response = response {
                self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didLoad: data)
                self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .notAllowed)
            } else {
                self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: UnexpectedValuesRepresentationError())
            }
            self.client?.urlProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
        }
        
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
    
    override func stopLoading() {
        dataTask?.cancel()
        dataTask = nil
    }
}
```

As you can see I am currently just using `private var token: String = "my.access.token"` to mock a token. I'd like to introduce a `TokenLoader` that will fetch my token from it's cache.

As the URL Loading system will initialize instances of my protocol as needed, I am not sure how I can inject this. It is currently registered using: `URLProtocol.registerClass(AuthInterceptor.self)`

Imagine I had an interface like this -

```swift
public typealias LoadTokenResult = Result<String, Error>
public protocol TokenLoader {
  func load(_ key: String, completion: @escaping (LoadTokenResult) -> Void)
}
```

I'd like to ensure this is testable so I'd expect to be able to stub this in a test case or use a spy.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever succeed?

Answer (score 1):

As it is seen `AuthInterceptor` does not depend on `TokenProvider` by instance level, so you can inject class level dependency and use shared `TokenProvider` to extract/load tokens (for instance, depending on URL). This gives possibility to inject cached token provider for testing easily

```
final class AuthInterceptor: URLProtocol {

    static var tokenProvider: TokenLoader?  // << inject here

    // initial value, will be loaded from to tokenProvider result
    private var token: String?  

    // ... other code
    
    // somewhere inside when needed, like
    Self.tokenProvider?.load(key) { [weak self] result in
       self?.token = try? result.get()

       // proceed with token if present ...
    }
}
```

so in UT scenario you can do something like

```
override func setUp {
   AuthInterceptor.tokenProvider = MockTokenProvider()
}

override func tearDown {
   AuthInterceptor.tokenProvider = nil // or some default if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option could be to use Generics for this.

```
protocol TokenProvider {
    static var token: String {get}
}

class MockTokenProvider: TokenProvider {
    static var token: String = "my.access.token"
}
```

And change AuthInterceptor like so:

```
    final class AuthInterceptor<T: TokenProvider>: URLProtocol {
      private var token: String = T.token
    ....
    ...
}
```

And register like so:

```
URLProtocol.registerClass(AuthInterceptor<MockTokenProvider>.self)
```

the above compiles in a playground, haven't tried it in a real project though..

Comment: This surely increases testability. But for my own sake I more interested in the "pass a depencency" part of the question. I want to be able to pass an instance of a class to be able to fetch my access token. Perhaps another question is required for this.